# How can I send a data image url to discord as an image file?

Tags: python, http, discord

how can I send a data image url to discord as an image file?
I have tried this

```py
import requests
import base64

# I hid the webhook so nobody trolls me and deletes the webhook
WEBHOOK_URL = "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/10304540869963366XXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXbiAhIF68Yt-yGBsSKlcKUsDvQdJ"

# Read the image file and encode it as a base64 string
with open("image.jpg", "rb") as image_file:
    image_data = image_file.read()
    image_data_base64 = base64.b64encode(image_data).decode("utf-8")

# Set the content type to "application/json"
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

# Set the payload of the request to a JSON object containing the base64-encoded image data
payload = {
    "username": "My Bot",
    "avatar_url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/434487340535382018/1053728327036305418/Screen_Shot_2022-12-17_at_12.40.07_PM.png",
    "content": f"data:image/jpeg;base64,{image_data_base64}",
}

# Make the POST request to the Discord webhook
response = requests.post(WEBHOOK_URL, headers=headers, json=payload)

# Check the status code of the response to ensure the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Image sent successfully")
else:
    print(f"Error sending image: {response.status_code}")
```

but I get `Error sending image: 400 (bad request)`
I got no idea what I could try, I have searched for couple hours but couldn't find a solution, I don't want to save the data url to hard disk then upload it, I am trying not to use the hard disk, only memory

Comment: are you trying to do this? https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#uploading-files

Comment: @LhasaDad what this? I don't understand it

Comment: Than we are both in same boat.  I could not figure out what you were wanting to do there.  At least it was not clear what your goal was.  knowing that might help us be able to advise you.